# Having Issue With Bootstrap 3 Collapse Margin Top in Small Screen

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can you please take a look at [this demo](http://www.bootply.com/HtqdVyKysq) and let me know how I can correct the code to add margin to the the `.collapse` only on small screens?

As You can see I have a custom height navbar with height of `100px` but bootstrap still displaying the `.collapse` on top of `50px` (approximately)! I tried to add

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-collapse{
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

it didn't work but when I add `!important` to the rule it works

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-collapse{
 margin-top: 50px !important;
}
```

**However**, this also adding unwanted margin to collapse class in big screen because of `!important` usage! Can you please let me know how I can fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use below code to **set style only on small screen**

`@media screen and (max-width: your size px) { css code}`

which means at device with max width screen browser shoud use this rules for css.

Also you can refer to ID `bs-example-navbar-collapse-1` and use something like that :

`#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1{
     margin-top: 50px;
 }`

Comment: Thanks for reply Jakub but my question is something else. The point is the `margin-top: 50px;` is not working and I have to use  `margin-top: 50px !important;` and this `!important` messing with the design